# ASP.NET: How to rewrite URL after slash

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a website that has language options of which one is turkish (tr).

The problem is that I deleted the language in the website (end user can no longer check the site in turkish) BUT the links can still be consulted via Google.

An example link looks like: http://example.com/page2.aspx?lang=tr .

What I want to do to solve this, is to redirect all requests to `?lang=tr` to my homepage (http://example.com).

Is this achievable via URL rewriting? How would I do this?

I have checked it in rewrite module but didn't came further than this:

```
  <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="?lang=tr" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}?lang=en" appendQueryString="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
    `<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
         <conditions>
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="lang=tr" />
        </conditions>
      </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>`